# NHibernate: Map same class to multiple tables depending on parent

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a model where multiple classes have a list of value types:

```
class Foo { public List<ValType> Vals; }
class Bar { public List<ValType> Vals; }
```

Foo and Bar are unrelated apart from that they both contain these vals. The rules for adding, removing, etc. the ValTypes are different for each class. I'd like to keep this design in my code.

There are times when I want to copy some Vals from a Foo to a Bar, for example.  In the database, each ValType has its own table, to keep it small, light (it just has the parent ID + 2 fields), and allow integrity checks. I know NHibernate says I should keep my objects as granular as the database, but that just makes my code uglier.

The best I've thought of so far is to make separate subclasses of ValType, one for each parent. Then I can map those at that level. Then, I'll hook up add and remove logic to auto-convert between the right subclasses, and actually store them in a private list that has the right subclass type. But this seemed a bit convoluted.

How can I map this in NHibernate (Fluent NHibernate if possible)?

Please let me know if this is a duplicate -- I'm not quite sure how to search this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an example on the [Google Code page for Fluent NHibernate](http://code.google.com/p/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Examples).

**Model**

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**Schema**

```
table Customer (
    Id int primary key
    Name varchar(100)
)

table CustomerAddress (
    CustomerID int,
    Address varchar(100)
)
```

**Mapping**

```
public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);

        WithTable("CustomerAddress", m =>
        {
            m.Map(x => x.Address);
        });
    }
}
```

In this example, an entity is split across two tables in the database. These tables are joined by a one-to-one on their keys. Using the WithTable feature, you can tell NHibernate to treat these two tables as one entity.

Comment: Hmm that'd be embarrassing :P. I'll check it out!

Comment: I see the link does not exist anymore, would like to see the solution

Comment: You can find it through the Wayback Machine (http://replay.waybackmachine.org/20090301015011/http://code.google.com/p/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Examples) but I can't find the relevant piece of code.

Comment: I believe WithTable is now Join

Answer (score 3):

At database level a solution would be to have:

```
Val(Id)
Bar(Id)
BarToVal(IdBar, IdVal)
FooToVal(IdFoo, IdVal)
```

I am not very sure how would these be mapped. Maybe something like:

```
// BarMap:  
HasManyToMany(x => x.Vals).WithTableName("BarToVal");

// FooMap:  
HasManyToMany(x => x.Vals).WithTableName("FooToVal");
```

Hope it's making sense...

Comment: Yea, I would do it that way except it's a bit of a performance hit. The tables are very small (20 bytes), and the PK is all the columns (ForeignID, Field1, Field2)